# read in a lot of argument in array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, arguments

I've got an array hnr3[], with 66 "data".

All of them are 0 in the beginning.

I need to via the arguments, (`batch.sh arg1 arg2 arg3`) for example `batch.sh /tmp/ 19 33 55` instruct the script that hnr3[19], hnr3[33] and hnr3[55] should be set to 1.

my issue is that I don't know if the hnr3 arguments will be starting on $2, $3 or $4 and no idea how many there will be.

is there anyway to make this working, and how? (I'm new to the array part)

Added:
What about adding a "keyword" to the arguments, like  `batch.sh /tmp/ -data 19,33,55`   and we read in the $* as a string, and somehow reads the data behind *-data*

Comment: When you say you don't know which argument the numbers will start at, what do you mean?  In your example you have `/tmp/` followed by numbers.  Are there other inputs that will have multiple directories or other things before the numbers?

Comment: @JohnZwinck there could be more , at least 1 (directory), max 3 (reset/manual)..

Comment: I was thinking about maybe if it looks for a keyword, in the $* argument, like -data 19,33,55  and it reads everything after -data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If arguments before numbers are optional, you can use getopts to handle them :

```
#!/bin/bash

manual=0
reset=0
tmpdir=""
while getopts mrt: c; do
    case $c in
    m) manual=1;;
    r) reset=1;;
    t) tmpdir="$OPTARG";;
    # You can add others optional arguments here
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

for arg; do
    hnr3[arg]=1
done

declare -p manual
declare -p reset
declare -p tmpdir
declare -p hnr3
```

Calling method:

```
./test.sh -m -t /tmp 19 33 55

# results:
declare -- manual="1"
declare -- reset="0"
declare -- tmpdir="/tmp"
declare -a hnr3=([19]="1" [33]="1" [55]="1")
```

Comment: how do I do if I want to have room for 4 arguments before the numbers? (4 strings) ?

Comment: I tried to add: p) pname="$OPTARG";;    , the same way you have, but it don't accept it.. I have declared it and set it to "" in the beginning..  $pname is empty..

Comment: Have you added `p:` after `getopts` ?

Comment: added it after t)  , I'm getting: illegal option -- p      wrote exactly like the tempdir ..

Comment: You need to change `getopts` line to `getopts mp:rt:` and in the calling method add `-p parameter`

Comment: getopts mrt: c; do     .. ah...  don't getopts mrtp: c; do   work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223586/discussion-between-philippe-and-jobe).